# function "input" and another function which allows to "find the biggest number"

Tags: javascript

I have to create a function which allows to enter 3 numbers

```
function userInput(){
    var number = readline.questionInt("Enter your number please : ");
}
```

Then, I have to use this function into another function to find the biggest number.

```
function numberBiggest(number){
    var big = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    userInput();
        if(number > big){
            big = number;
        }
    }
    return big; 
}
```

My problem is that I retrieve each time the value 0.

```
var biggest = numberBiggest();
console.log("The biggest number is => " + biggest);

function userInput(){
    var number = readline.questionInt("Enter your number please : ");
}

function numberBiggest(number){
    var big = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    userInput();
        if(number > big){
            big = number;
        }
    }
    return big; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is the number is defined inside userInput() it's value in the global context is  undefined and according to The [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) in javascript undefined equal to 0 when comparing to number

you have to return it from the userInput function  :

```
var biggest = numberBiggest();
console.log("The biggest number is => " + biggest);
function userInput(){
    var number = readline.questionInt("Enter your number please : ");
    return number ;
}

function numberBiggest(number){
    var big = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    number = userInput();
        if(number > big){
            big = number;
        }
    }
    return big; 
}
```